# Using Devise with multiple namespaces for the same Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, devise

I want to use Devise with two namespaces: an API namespace, and the default namespace,
but the two seem to be conflicting when a user tries to sign in.
Meaning, whichever namespace that references Devise first ends up
being the final redirection place. Ex: If I try to create a new session
under the default namespace it will fail on that user session path,
and then attempt to create the session on the API/v1 sessions path.

How do I make the two act independently?

They are both referencing a User object. The user_sessions controller
for the default namespace is 'user_sessions'. The user_sessions
controller for the API/V1 namespace is '/api/v1/user_sessions'

```
    ---- ROUTES.RB -------
    MySite::Application.routes.draw do
    namespace :api do
   namespace :v1 do
     devise_for :users,:controllers => { :sessions => "api/v1/
user_sessions",:registrations=>"users" }
     ......
   end
 end
 devise_for :users,:controllers => { :sessions =>"user_sessions",:registrations=>"users" } do
    post 'users/sign_in' => 'user_sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    get 'users/sign_in' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    get 'users/sign_up' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    match 'users/sign_out' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    <.....>
 end
```

----- DEFAULT NAMESPACE USER_SESSIONS_CONTROLLER -----

```
class UserSessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
....
end
----
```

API NAMESPACE USER_SESSIONS_CONTROLLER ---- (this goes to my custom Devise base controller marked below)

```
class Api::V1::UserSessionsController < Api::V1::DeviseBaseController
...
end
```

---- API NAMESPACE CUSTOM DEVISE BASE CONTROLLER ----

```
class Api::V1::DeviseBaseController < Devise::SessionsController
       respond_to :json
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out that this isn't possible with Devise, you have to have one sign-in/sign out source.

Clean solution: Create routes for both your API and Web namespaces that point back to the same Devise controller code (say, /user/sessions). In there, call partials for the appropriate response (JSON, HTML). Those partials can sit in the view directories for each namespace, keeping things clean.

Answer (score 1):

You should need to define two diffrent roles for user like admin and end user.

and then define these routes for him

```
 FourtySixLabs::Application.routes.draw do

    namespace :admin do
     resources :posts
    end

    namespace :end_user do
      resources :posts
    end


  devise_for :users, :controllers => {
    :sessions => "users/sessions",
    :confirmation => "users/confirmations",
    :passwords => "users/passwords",
    :registrations => "users/registrations",
  }


  devise_for :users, as: :user do
    get 'admin', :to => 'users/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    get "end_user", :to => "users/sessions#new"
    get "sign_out", :to => "users/sessions#destroy"
  end

 end
```

And then admin will login from this url
       localhost:3000/admin

And then end_user will login from this url
      localhost:3000/end_user

For defining roles see this

[Rails : Adding an admin role using devise who can see all the users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222400/rails-adding-an-admin-role-using-devise-who-can-see-all-the-users/10222813#10222813)

Hope you will get idea

Comment: If you look at the code I've posted, I've done exactly that. How is your proposed solution any different?