# How to have two devise authentication models/routes for Active Admin namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I have an ActiveAdmin instance that used to serve only Admin for my company users. It came to be that we needed our clients to manage some other models. On the activeadmin part it looked simple. I just created a separate namespace and it worked. When I tried to create two different login endpoints is where things got complex.

This is my routes.rb file:

```
scope '/admin' do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  devise_for :client_admins, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

Problem is: activeadmin uses the default namespace (the one for admin_users) to generate the routes. Is there a way to do this without overriding and writing my own auth controllers for the client_admins?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  devise_for :teachers, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config.merge(:path => :admin)
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  root 'application#root'
end
```

config/initializers/active_admin.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.site_title = "Admin"
  config.default_namespace = :superadmin
  config.namespace :superadmin do |admin|
    admin.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
    admin.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
    admin.logout_link_path = :destroy_admin_user_session_path
  end

  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.authentication_method = :authenticate_teacher!
    admin.current_user_method = :current_teacher
    admin.logout_link_path = :destroy_teacher_session_path
    admin.root_to = 'dashboard#index'
  end
end
```

Rails 5.0.0.1, Devise 4.2.0, ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre4

Comment: I think for the devise_for :teachers, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config.merge(:path => :admin) path cant be admin, it will be something like path: :xyz @across

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible: [Using Devise with multiple namespaces for the same Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285177/using-devise-with-multiple-namespaces-for-the-same-model)

I would use rolify and cancancan to create an `:admin` and `:client` role.

https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan