# Setting roles for a users in rails with cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am working on a rails application and it requires two different types of roles. One is Employee and other is Admin.

Cancan documentation says that it assumes there is a user or current_user method in the application.

So how can I use cancan to set roles for employee and manager in my app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this

write this in application helper

```
def is_employee?(user)
  emp_role = Role.find(:first, :conditions => ["name = ?", "Employee"])
  return user.roles.include?(emp_role)
end

def is_admin?(user)
  admin_role = Role.find(:first, :conditions => ["name = ?", "Admin"])
  return user.roles.include?(admin_role)
end
```

And abily look like this

```
     class Ability
       include CanCan::Ability
       include ApplicationHelper

    def initialize(user)
      # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
       #
      user ||= Employee.new # guest user (not logged in)
      if is_admin?(user)
       can :manage, :all
       # cannot :manage, IpAddress
     elsif is_employee?(user)

      #your code
     end
```

For define roles see it

```
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222400/rails-adding-an-admin-role-using-devise-who-can-see-all-the-users/10222813#10222813
```

It sure works...

Comment: I don't have a user class. I have Employee class and from there I want to set roles.

Comment: yes I have installed devise and setup it to the Employee model

Comment: Is there any option for overriding the user with some other name in cancan ?

Comment: Only chenge in ability where User.new replace with Employee.new